# Extracting numbers before several text strings in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract numbers before several strings in free-text descriptions for different people. So I have e.g. 100 free-text descriptions for 100 people which contains the age of the person. The problem is,so far I am able to extract the number correctly, but I also need the unit of the number e.g. year, month, day. Further on, sometimes more than one age is provided, so I also need the information of all age informations reported in numbers and unit.

So far I tried this:

dataset%>%mutate(Ageinfo = str_extract(dataset$Freetext "\d+(?= years old)|\d+(?= year old)|\d+(?= month old)|\d+(?= months old)|\d+(?= *-year-old)|\d+(?= *-month-old)|\d+(?= days old)|\d+(?= *-days-old)|\d+(?= *-year old)|\d+(?= year-old)|\d+(?= Jahre alt)"))%>%View

What I get looks like:

| Freetext | Ageinfo |

| Text 3-years-old  | 3   |

| Text 5 months old  | 5  |

So the extracting works pretty well. However, I have the problem, that age can be given in years, months or days. So I would also need the unit which led to the extraction of the number. Something like this:

| Freetext | Ageinfo | Unit |

| Text 3-years-old   | 3   | -years-old |

| Text 5 months old  | 5   | months old |

In addition, sometimes more than one age is provided in the free-text e.g. age of the mother and her son.
So, what I also need is to see if more than one age was reported in number and unit as before. So something like that:

| Freetext | Ageinfo | Unit | Ageinfo2 | Unit2 |

| Text 3-years-old   | 3   | -years-old | NA | NA |

| Text 5 months old and 45 year old mother  | 5   | months old | 45 | year old |

I would be very happy if someone could help me out here.

As an simple example:

```
dataset <- data.frame(Freetext = c("A 3-year-old body was at the supermarket", "A 45 year old mother was at the supermarket with her little 5 months old boy"), Furtherinfo = c("ID1", "ID2"))
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the text in the question with the output of `dput(head(freetext, n))` where n is large enough to provide a sample of all cases.

Comment: I've added a simple example. I can not add the real data and I do not have similar data. So I hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this should get you started (based on your sample data)

```
lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(dataset$Freetext, "[0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+"), 
       lubridate::period)

# [[1]]
# [1] "3y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "45y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" "5m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

It will return non-period numbers as NA

```
x <- "A 3-year-old boy was at the supermarket with his 45 year old mother \n
      and they bought 10 apples for his 10 weeks old sister"
lapply(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "[0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]+"), 
       lubridate::period)
[[1]]
[1] "3y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"  "45y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" NA                   "70d 0H 0M 0S"
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but I think this would not handle my problem, because, I have several other numbers in my free-texts, and I only want to extract those which are related to the age of the persons. I think your solution will give me all number reported following any letters, right?

Comment: have you actually checked, it should return NA on all non-period number-word combinations? Also; if your sample dows not represent critical issues in your production data, it is baaaad sample data ;-) please update.. also, see edited answer

Comment: Yes I know, I am sorry for that, that I do not have a better example. The problem is that in my dataset, I also have other number with years, months and date units which are not age related.